# How to put some tab/indentation in numbering?

Tags: enumerate

How do I put some tab/indentation in numbering (enumerate package) from this

[image: Before]

into this

[image: After]

The code that I've written is as follows:

```
\begin{enumerate}
  \item To show that the first component of FTTM, namely magnetic contour 
        plane can be viewed as Jordan canonical matrices under matrix 
        multiplication.
  \item To present three real time examples of semigroup of Jordan canonical 
        matrices.
  \item To build the theoretical (mathematical) foundation of the elementary 
        components of the semigroup of Jordan canonical matrices; i.e. to 
        find Jordan-Chevalley decompositions (wreath decompositions) for our 
        semigroup of strictly upper triangular matrices under matrix 
        multiplication of EEG signals recorded during epileptic seizure.
\end{enumerate}
```

Comment: Welcome! Please post code we can copy-paste compile to reproduce the first image. Then we can try to show you how to modify it to produce the second.

Comment: isn't this (desired result) standard form of `enumerate` list?

Comment: I used the standard {enumerate} package and get the previous result not the desired result. The first one is actually from Latex and the desired result is typed using Microsoft Word. @Zarko

Comment: Is there any way I can manipulate the indentation on enumerate environment?

Comment: @AmirulAizad, of course it is. but for further help please provide complete small document beginning with `\documentclass{...}` followed with your (relevant) preamble and example of your code and ending with `\end{document}`. without having this is impossible to help you. help us to help you :-).